# How can I call the edit component within another file?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a project and this project is for the owners of the purchase for the purchase of cars and many other operations, but I have a table with several columns, and within these columns there is a column I listen to action and this column contains a button called Edit and I want when I click on the Edit button to be used The component of the modification within this file, how can I do this?
And it is the Edit file in which the Edit form is located.
Edit.vue:

```
<template>
  <v-row justify="center">
    <v-dialog v-model="editDialog" persistent max-width="1050px" height="400px">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn
          fab
          accent
          class="grey lighten-1 margin pa-4"
          dark
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="on"
        >
          <v-icon>
            mdi-pencil
          </v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <v-card>
        <v-layout>
          <v-flex xs12>
            <div class="myfont pl-5">
              <v-card-title>
                <span> Edit Car</span>
              </v-card-title>
            </div>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
        <v-divider xs12></v-divider>
        <v-layout>
          <v-flex xs12>
            <v-card-text>
              <v-container>
                <v-row>
                  <v-col cols="12">
                    <v-text-field
                      name="name"
                      label="Name"
                      id="name"
                      class="colorLabel"
                      v-model="editedName"
                      multi-line
                      required
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="12">
                    <v-text-field
                      name="priceOfSale"
                      label="Price Of Sale"
                      id="priceOfSale"
                      v-model="editedPrice"
                      class="colorLabel"
                      multi-line
                      required
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="12">
                    <v-text-field
                      name="numberOfSeats"
                      label="NumberOfSeats"
                      id="numberOfSeats"
                      v-model="editedNumberOfSeats"
                      multi-line
                      required
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
              </v-container>
            </v-card-text>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
        <v-divider></v-divider>
        <v-layout>
          <v-flex xs12>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-btn class="myfont pl-5 text-right" text @click="onSaveChanges">
                Save
              </v-btn>
              <v-btn
                class="myfont pl-5 text-center"
                text
                @click="editDialog = false"
              >
                Cancel
              </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-row>
</template>
<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
import ActionsTypes from "../store/types/actions-types";
export default {
  props: ["car"],
  data() {
    return {
      editedName: this.car.name,
      editedPrice: this.car.price,
      editedNumberOfSeats: this.car.seatsNumber,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      editCarInformations: ActionsTypes.EDIT_CAR_ACTION,
    }),
    onSaveChanges() {
      const UpdatedCar = { ...this.car };
      UpdatedCar.name = this.editedName;
      UpdatedCar.price = this.editedPrice;
      UpdatedCar.seatsNumber = this.editedNumberOfSeats;
      this.editCarInformations(UpdatedCar);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

This file, in which there is a table containing several columns, and the last column is Action, which contains the Modify button, the Modify button, and when I press it, the universe of the amendment is called.
viewAllCars:

```
<template>
  <v-app class="bg">
    <v-container>
      <v-card
        class="mx-auto mt-5 pa-3"
        max-width="100%"
        id="limited-products"
        :style="'border: 0px solid #D50000;'"
      >
        <v-btn class="red accent-4 color myfont pl-3" @click="onCreateCar">
          evict Cashig 
        </v-btn>
        <v-data-table
          :headers="tableHeaders"
          :items="loadedCarsGetter"
          :page.sync="page"
          :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
          hide-default-footer
          class="elevation-1"
          @page-count="pageCount = $event"
        >
          <template #[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
            <v-btn icon @click="edit(item.id)">
              <v-icon>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn icon @click="delete (item.id)">
              <v-icon>mdi-delete</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>  
        <!-- pagination -->
        <div class="text-center pt-2">
          <v-pagination v-model="page" :length="pageCount"></v-pagination>
          <v-text-field
            :value="itemsPerPage"
            label="Items per page"
            type="number"
            min="-1"
            max="15"
            @input="itemsPerPage = parseInt($event, 10)"
            class="pl-7 pr-7"
          ></v-text-field>
        </div>
      </v-card>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>
<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex";
import ActionsTypes from "../../store/types/actions-types";
import GettersTypes from "../../store/types/getters-types";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      page: 1,
      pageCount: 0,
      itemsPerPage: 10
    };
  },
  created() {},
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      loadedCarsGetter: GettersTypes.GET_CAR_FORM_GETTER,
      tableHeaders: GettersTypes.GET_HEADERS_TABLE_GETTER,
    }),
  },
  mounted() {
    // this.loadedCarsGetter();
    this.loadedCarsAction();
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      editcardispatcher: ActionsTypes.EDIT_CAR_ACTION,
      deletecardispatcher: ActionsTypes.DELETE_CAR_ACTION,
      loadedCarsAction: ActionsTypes.GET_ALL_CAR_ACTION
    }),
    edit() {
      this.editcardispatcher({});
    },
    delete(){
      this.deletecardispatcher(
        this.car.id
    )
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't need the "v-row" in the Edit.vue. Remove it.

As you have the button as the activator, you should just add the component as Avraham mentioned. But you need to know that there are some caveats with this approach

- This is gonna be increasing the memory usage by the browser. As a separate instance of Edit.vue will be added to the DOM for each row in your table.
- Each Edit.vue instance will preserve the data in it with the changes that the user might make. And you'll have to handle the data resets.

A better solution would be to add only one instance of Edit.vue and add/remove the component from the DOM using a v-if.

This will keep your table using one instance of Edit.vue, and the addition and removal of the component will handle the data reset.

Something like this

In the file that contains the v-data-table, update the template as follows

```html
<template>
  ......
  <v-data-table ...>
    ...
    <template #[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
      <v-btn icon @click="edit(item.id)">
        <v-icon>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn icon @click="delete(item.id)">
        <v-icon>mdi-delete</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </template>
    ...
  </v-data-table>
  <edit :car="item" v-if="showEditDialog = true" @closed="showEditDialog = false" />
  ......
</template>

<script>
import Edit from 'Edit.vue'

export default {
  components: { Edit },
  data: () =({
    item: {},
    showEditDialog: false,
  }),
  methods: {
    edit(item) {
      this.item = item
      this.showEditDialog = true
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

In your Edit.vue, add a watcher for the "editDialog" property to emit an event to remove the edit dialog from the DOM.

```js
watch: {
  editDialog(val){
    if(!val)
      this.$emit('closed')
  }
}
```

And remove this part from the Edit.Vue

```html
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn
          fab
          accent
          class="grey lighten-1 margin pa-4"
          dark
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="on"
        >
          <v-icon>
            mdi-pencil
          </v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </template>
```

Good luck.

Comment: this is a better solution

Answer (score 1):

You should import the `Edit.vue` component in the car viewer component and use it instead of the edit button:

```html
...
<template #[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
  <!-- Pass the item to the `car` prop -->
  <edit :car="item" />
  <v-btn icon @click="delete (item.id)">
    <v-icon>mdi-delete</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</template>
...
<script>
import Edit from 'Edit.vue' // make sure the path to the component is correct

export default {
  components: { Edit },
  ...
};
</script>
```